# CSS - Select either first row or head row in HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I have a mixed set of tables on the website. Some have the `thead` present and others directly start with a tr without having `thead`.

Since I want the first row to become sticky and scroll with the user till last row in the table, I added the following code:

```
.wp-block-table tr:first-child {
  left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 25vw;
    background: white;
}
```

But the issue now is that the table without `thead` scrolls but when a table has `thead` present then the scroll starts from the second row (i.e after skipping the `thead`)

I know I need to fix the table HTML so that they are consistent everywhere but in the meantime is there any CSS selector which can handle the sticky scrolling in both the cases.

If `thead` is not present then use my above code and if `thead` is present then I will need to add some extra CSS code. I need help with that extra code. Never been in such a situation before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `first-child` to find the first child (`thead` or `tbody`) and the `first-child` inside of it to find the first `tr`:

```css
table > *:first-child > tr:first-child {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>THEAD</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>TBODY</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

----------------------------------------

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>THEAD</td></tr>
        <tr><td>TBODY</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh! I finished typing and testing my answer and came back to see that you'd beat me to it. This is the correct solution. +1